# Error in reading excel sheet header

Tags: java, apache-poi, fileinputstream

I have one excel file with 4 different sheets to be read for my project. All 4 sheets contain different headers and different number of columns. When I delete all the headers and make everything look same by having same number of columns the code works. But I have no authority to modify the excel sheet as I wish.
Please somebody suggest me a way how to make the excel file to be read with headers even with different number of columns. Here is my code to read excel file:

```
public class ReadExcelFileAndStore {

    public List getTheFileAsObject(String filePath){
        List <Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            //System.out.println(numberOfSheets);
            //loop through each of the sheets
           for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {

               // Get first sheet from the workbook
               HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
               String sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(i);

               // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
               Iterator <Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
               Row headerRow= rowIterator.next();

               while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                   // Get Each Row
                   Row row = rowIterator.next();

                   // For each row, iterate through each columns
                   Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                   Employee employee = new Employee();

                   while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                       Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                       int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

                       switch (columnIndex + 1) {

                           case 1:
                               employee.setEmpName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                               break;
                           case 2:
                               employee.setExtCode((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                               break;
                       }
                   }
                   employeeList.add(employee);
               }
           }
            file.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return employeeList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting, and at what point are you getting it? Also, would you be able to share an example Excel file containing the sheets/columns you have to work with? The one you're currently trying to read with all the actual names and numbers removed and replaced with dummy values would work. I'd also only need like one or two rows on each sheet.

Comment: I am getting an alert message saying "localhost:8080 says error error" when I load the page